# How to copy a SAS numeric value into missing fields after meeting conditions

Tags: sas

I have a set of records with hospitaL visit dates and visit times that are inconsistent in how they occur, and I would like to fill in missing visit times with visit times from other dates.

For example, some visit dates have visit times, while others are missing visit times. My question is: In the event that a visit date is present BUT without a visit time, how can I simply print a visit time from a previous visit date (with a visit time) into that missing slot?  Please see the image of Have and Want for a better illustration and description.

Conditions: if visit time is blank then print the visit time that appears elsewhere in the table.  if visit time is blank and visit time does not appear anywhere else for that date in the file then keep it blank.

I am curious if I need to incorporate a loop or simply an if-then print statement.

'''if code_time ne then print the values in the last.code_time'''

```
data want;
infiles datalines;
length code_date $50. code_time $9.;
input code_date code_time;
datalines;
19-AUG-2010 .
19-AUG-2010 .
19-AUG-2010 16:56:00
20-AUG-2010 .
20-AUG-2010 17:12:00
23-AUG-2010 13:10:00
23-AUG-2010 13:19:00
26-AUG-2010 .
30-AUG-2010 19:30:00
09-SEP-2010 .
03-DEC-2010 .
;
quit;
run;
```

Thank you all.
CB

**Have**

[image: Have]

**Want**

[image: Want]

Comment: Can you please expand your sample to deal with a situation in your last record where you have different times on the same data and what you expect the output to be in that situation. Filling in missing is easy but when you have multiple options to chose from that's more complicated.

Comment: HI Reeza, Thanks for your question. In the situation where the last record has different times on the same date, then do nothing. It is a separate visit on the same day and will be treated as such. So, nothing needs to happen in that case. Does this make sense?

Comment: You should add a case where you have the last situation and have missing data as well.

Comment: That's a fair point to add to be safe. Any suggestions on code to accomplish this?

Comment: Type your data out in Excel and add some rows. FYI - if you post pictures you're less likely to get a response because someone has to type out your data to work with it. Your final solution will likely involve lag/retain.

Comment: Posting your data in a `datalines` format will allow us to get you a solution faster.

Comment: Thank you @Reeza and Stu I have added a little bit of the code if that helps. I have looked at retain and lag as you suggested. It looks like the right idea, but I am stuck.

Comment: I have not yet come to a conclusion on how to bring a code_time into a missing row for the same date. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert your data from characters to SAS dates and times. This will make it easier to work with later. Change your `input` statement as follows:

```
format code_date date9. code_time time.;
input code_date:date11. code_time:time.;
```

When doing a data step, use the `retain` statement to keep a running value that always holds the most recent time. If you have specific conditions in which it should not fill in a time, you can add that logic to either set `last_code_time` to missing or not overwrite a value.

If values need to be filled in before a non-missing value is encountered, you'll need re-sort the dataset by `code_date descending code_time` and do a second pass with the same code.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by code_date;
    retain last_code_time;

    if(first.code_date) then call missing(last_code_time);

    if(NOT missing(code_time) ) then last_code_time = code_time;
        else code_time = last_code_time;

    drop last_code_time;
run;
```

If you have SAS/ETS, you can also do this with less code using `proc expand`.

```
proc expand data=want out=have(drop=time);
    by code_date;
    convert code_time / method=step;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @Stu. It seems the code is pulling some errors. When replacing the input statement with your suggestion. The log states: NOTE 484-185: Format $DATE was not found or could not be loaded. It states this error for both the format and input statement.

Comment: Try removing the length statement so they are not treated as characters.

Comment: Removing the length statement worked! Columns are now treated appropriately. Next step, after submitting the retain code you suggested, I am not observing any changes. There are no errors present in the log. I can share a screenshot if that helps?

Comment: The code will need to be run twice: once in the originally sorted direction, then again after resorting by `code_date descending code_time`. The first pass accounts for gaps in-between or after values. The second pass fills in any initial leading missing values. This ensures that the original order is kept where there are in-between or trailing missing values.

Comment: That is a fascinating! It worked! Thank you for teaching me this new technique and for your active participation. Cheers! PS. I tried to upvote your answer. I have <15 reputation, so it is not displaying.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad it worked. Now there are ways you can do it all in one pass in a data step, but it's more complex. If it doesn't take long to do multiple passes, this method will be easy to support in the long run. Sometimes it's all about optimizing supportabilty vs. efficiency.